# Translating errno to string in vxworks

Tags: c, vxworks, errno

In vxworks, when an api call returns ERROR, it often sets errno.

We can access this using errnoGet(), and, from the shell, we can translate that into a meaningful string using printErrno()

Is there a function I can call from my C code that will do this translation and return a char* suitable?

The example below illustrates, however note that this is a MVCE, and use of printf is for example only - in the real world this would be used as part of a custom error handler that does not do screen output.

eg

```
STATUS badFunc()
{
    errnoSet(S_someErrnoVal);
    return ERROR;
}

void anotherFunc()
{
    if(badFunc()==ERROR)
    {
        //currently, I end up just calling printErrno() here
        //but if there was some function errnoToText() i could do something like:

        printf("badFunc failed, errno %d, error string%s",errnoGet(), errnoToText(errnoGet()));
    }
}
```

I am sure I used to have such a function available, but I cant find any reference in the programmers guide.

Comment: do you have access to `strerror` (`string.h`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strerror()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html):

```
fprint( stderr, "error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel if the error string should just be printed. `perror` does exactly that (to `stdout`).

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: of course, but the question was about a function that returns the error as a string. the `printf()`s may just be examples

Comment: @JensGustedt perror (and printErrno() ) do print direct to stdout. You will note from the question that I am aware of that. But what I wanted was a way of retrieving the error string, and formating that myself - maybe to write to stdout myself, or to write to a file, or ......

Answer (score -2):

From the vxWorks :

A string constant associated with errno can be displayed using printErrno( ) if the errno value has a corresponding string entered in the error-status symbol table, statSymTbl. See the VxWorks API reference for errnoLib for details on error-status values and building statSymTbl.

So to print String associated with an errno: printErrno(errno)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't actually answer the question. You will note from reading the question I am already aware of printErrno, which is fine from the C shell or if you just want it displayed to stdout. However the question was about how can I get the string, to use elsewhere, eg to log into a file or as part of a custom error message.

Comment: Hi Mjs... then in that case you can use the same logic which printErrno is using :   Below is the snippet:                                                 if ((_func_symFind != NULL) &&
     (_func_symFind (statSymTbl, &symbolDesc) == OK))
     {
     if (symbolDesc.value != (SYM_VALUE)((long)errNo))
  printf ("Unknown errno = %#x.\n", errNo);
     else
  printf ("errno = %#x : %s.\n", errNo, symbolDesc.name);      In your case you can use symbolDesc.name  for your refrence and use it anywhere. Or if you are designing your own error handler then you need to write you custom error message

Comment: If you think, it ans you correctly, then I can edit the main ans. There is no other built-in function for this request i guess.

Comment: No. The accepted answer is correct, which is to use strerror.